# Passing a date through angular directive attibute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In the HTML code of an angular directive I got

```
ng-attr-from="{{some date}}"
```

In directive's code I got

```
var dateString = attrs.from;
```

`dateString` receives `"2015-08-06T09:45:23.315Z"`

Problem: I need a date object to which I can apply `format(...)` later.

I tried :

```
var date = Date.pase(dateString);
```

But `date` receives `NaN`.

How can I get it as a date object ?

Comment: If you try a `new Date(dateString)`, what is the result ?

Comment: var x = new Date("2015-08-06T10:52:31.025Z") , x receives "Invalid date".

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
var a = "2015-08-06T09:45:23.315Z";
var b = new Date(a);
```

then you can even do this :

```
var c = Date.parse(b);
```

Comment: var x = new Date("2015-08-06T10:52:31.025Z") , x receives "Invalid date"

Comment: @TTT thats strange I tested this in https://repl.it/languages/JavaScript and it worked fine

Comment: @TTT could you post a plunkr in which you can reproduce your error please.